# JQuery message confirmation asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have problem with this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a.show").click(function () {

          $("#Box").slideDown(500);
          //if i return false the message conformation show and stopped but i have
          //problem the Query String this not passing in the URL
          // and if i return true the message show and hide quickly but
          //the QueryString passing in the URL    
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Note:** in my solution i have do **message confirmation** for deleting but i will design my message box and i will do two button (Yes, NO) if Client click on yes the code of deleting execute (in this code i have the **Query String** :( )

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is? It isn't clear

Comment: the problem is when I return false the query string does not pass in URL and my message box show (in my class css is hidden). if i return true the query syting pass in URL but my message show and hidden quickly !!

Answer (score 0):

So when the user clicks a link, you want some http request sent to the server, but you don't want to navigate away from the page? Instead you simply want to manipulate the objects on the page?

I think you're looking for this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/9fg8dm3z/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.show").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: ""
        }).done(function() {
              $("#Box").slideDown(500);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Obviously you'll want to change the URL. But when the user clicks the link an http request is made to the url. When the response is received, the "done" function will be executed, showing the "Box".